# Why are certain anime not on YouTube?

Tags: anime-production

Anime like Naruto Shippuden are there on YouTube, but One Piece is not there.
Why is it so?

Comment: The default state of existence for all anime is "not on YouTube". If the rights-holders for _One Piece_ have not uploaded it to YouTube, it won't be on YouTube...

Comment: I'm not sure if they are full episodes but Funimation who holds distribution rights for the US posts anime on their channel. though with it geoblocked from Australians i can't confirm if they are full episodes

Comment: @Memor-X: they do upload full episodes, but only of some series, and sometimes, they only have the first 1-2 episodes of the series. (I recently watched the entirety of _Noir_ through their YouTube channel; in contrast, I was only able to watch 2 episodes of _Selector Infected Wixoss_ on YouTube.)

Comment: @Maroon well that more or less confirms that anime can be on youtube however in regards to say *Noir*, if anyone else uploads it on youtube Funimation can flag for removal

Comment: [Not sure if that Naruto Shippuden is legal on YouTube...](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2011-09-21/crunchyroll-tv-tokyo-sue-youtube-users-for-unauthorized-anime-uploading).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking why a certain anime series is not in a certain video sharing site and not about the anime itself. Thus, not within Anime SE's scope.

Comment: @AyaseEri:  I'd argue that this isn't wildly off-topic, as we've even got [a list of legal streaming services](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal) which really should be moved over to this side.  Perhaps a Meta post on it would suffice?  There's a concise answer to this question but policy/procedure would benefit if we had a side discussion about it.

Comment: @AyaseEri i would argue that it is on topic because we have had questions on the logistics of anime localization and distribution like if Gitama on Steam is any different to Crunchyroll or if it's ok to start a new site and upload anime, albeit that i shouldn't assume bad will but this questions reads like *"why can't i pirate One Piece through youtube like i can with Naruto"* (though that can be cleared up by verifying that the channel these series are on is a licensed distributor)

Comment: @AyaseEri I'd expect to find a dupe to a more general "why anime/manga is not published in every country/media?" but apparently failed to do so.

Comment: @^ which is why I vote to close this.

Comment: My view is that this is a fair question from someone who has not yet learned about copyright law.  Instead of shutting him down, an explanation like that provided by @senshin is the way to go.  I'll add to senshin's response by saying that the copyright holders for popular anime make much more money in licensing their properties than they would ever earn on YouTube, and putting it on YouTube devalues the property to the point that no one will license it.  What you see on YouTube is either illegal and not yet caught, or the rights holders don't expect to make any decent money in any case.

Answer (score 0):

People may have uploaded episodes of *One Piece* on YouTube, but they have been taken down by copyright claims, therefore causing them to be inaccessible or disappear. Another possibility is that no one has uploaded an episode to YouTube yet (which is however unlikely).